# Delete entry from intermediary model if m2m changed

Tags: python, django

I've got a question. I want to delete the record in 'through' model, while editing Competition model in Django Admin. It is  about editing m2m field 'competition_field'. Example: Competition with fields('Height', 'Width), and I will remove 'width' from m2m, and nothing will change in model 'FieldValues' I have tried everything I know, but without some succes.

This is my **models.py**

```
class Fields(models.Model):
field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Competitions(models.Model):
    competition_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    competition_field = models.ManyToManyField(Fields)

class Applications(models.Model):
    application_applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application_competition = models.ForeignKey(Competitions, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    application_value = models.ManyToManyField(Fields, through='FieldsValues')

class FieldsValues(models.Model):
    catch_fields = models.ForeignKey(Fields, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    application = models.ForeignKey(Applications, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.TextField(null=True, default=0)
```

Comment: But the `Competition` model is not referenced by the `through` model

Comment: Thank you, is it real to do some releations for this?